# Privileges in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created a user in oracle and grant all privileges to the user but when I execute my table I get an error saying insufficient privileges, all the tables before this table was successful.

This the Privileges:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
 create USER A1_18019497_ADDB7311 identified by Sileshan1234;
 Grant all PRIVILEGES to A1_18019497_ADDB7311;

 SELECT username, account_status FROM dba_users
```

This is my table:
--Create table Billing

```
    CREATE TABLE A1_18019497_ADDB7311.BILLING(
    BillID INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID),
    BillDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID VARCHAR(6) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID),
    PRIMARY KEY(BillID));
```

This is the error:

```
Error starting at line : 62 in command -
CREATE TABLE A1_18019497_ADDB7311.BILLING(
    BillID INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID),
    BillDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID VARCHAR(6) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID),
    PRIMARY KEY(BillID))
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

Comment: What user is running this script?

Comment: Also, do you know what the _ORACLE_SCRIPT parameter does? You shouldn't be using it. This is true for pretty much all undocumented underscore parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all the tables before this table was successful

So you have other CREATE TABLE statements in the script, and it's just this one which is failing?

Then the problem is not with the GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES. (That's problematic for other reasons).

Looking at your statement I notice that you are prefixing the table name with the schema name:

```
CREATE TABLE A1_18019497_ADDB7311.BILLING
```

Does this mean you are running the script from another user, say SYS or some other DBA account? If so that might explain the issue.

Your BILLING table has two foreign keys but the references don't prefix the table name with the schema. This means the Oracle won't reference tables in A1_18019497_ADDB7311 but in the running schema, or some other schema which has made grants to public. The thing is, GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES grants system privileges  and ANY object privileges but not privileges on individual objects. To create a foreign key against a table in another schema you need that schema to grant you the REFERENCES privilege on the table.

Alternatively, if want you actually want is keep the foreign keys within the schema you're trying to create you need to prefix the foreign key clauses with the schema name:

```
CREATE TABLE A1_18019497_ADDB7311.BILLING(
    BillID INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerID INT REFERENCES A1_18019497_ADDB7311.CUSTOMER(CustomerID),
    BillDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EmployeeID VARCHAR(6) REFERENCES A1_18019497_ADDB7311.EMPLOYEE(EmployeeID),
    PRIMARY KEY(BillID))
```

Better ways of achieving this:

1. Connecting to A1_18019497_ADDB7311 and running the script
2. Use `alter session set current_schema=A1_18019497_ADDB7311` to run the script from a power user without having to prefix all the referenced objects.

---

A couple of by the ways.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES is not good practice. Explicitly give users the only privileges they need. Get into good habits now, you'll be glad you did.

Do not use _ORACLE_SCRIPT. This is intended for use by Oracle only. This is largely true of all underscore parameters, which are undocumented precisely to discourage people from using them. Unfortunately this also makes them attractive to people, especially beginners. The problem is, because they are undocumented it's easy to miss their side effects.

In this case, _ORACLE_SCRIPT is used by Oracle to identify their official scripts. Why do they need it? Setting the parameter flags all the tables created in the session as ORACLE_MAINTAINED in DBA_TABLES. Which is bad for your situation, because it causes confusion - you can no longer distinguish official Oracle tables for your application's tables - and potentially cause problems with upgrades and other system maintenance activities. You have gained no benefit from using this parameter but have corrupted your data dictionary: not a good bargain.

Don't use this parameter in your own scripts. And generally don't use underscore parameters unless you know exactly what you're doing. There's lots of bad advice on the internet about using underscore parameters from people who don't understand the implications.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to grant `CREATE TABLE` privilege separately, it isn't included in `all privileges`.

---

By the way, I'd suggest you **not** to do it that way. Don't grant unnecessary privileges, especially if you don't know who and how is going to (ab)use them. Grant only required privileges, one-by-one, when needed. If you want, create a **role** and grant those privileges to a role, and then grant role to your users.